# a tags doesnt work after sending mail with php

Tags: php, html

i am trying to send an email via php using the function mail(), in the mail i want to include a link, the problem is that in my outlock it shows the link but wont open it in chrome (when i hover over the link with my mouse it gives me /blocked:\ before the link itself, and in gmail it doesnt even show the link only shows the link text as plain text. can you spot any problems?

```
$link = 'stackoverflow.com';
$emailTo = 'root@localhost.com';
$body = '<body><a href=\"'.$link.'\">click me</a>  <br/></body>';
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0 \n" ;
$headers .= "From: me@gmail.com";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8 \n";
mail($emailTo, 'title', $body, $headers);
```

i would appritiate any help

EDIT: i dont know if it mean anything but when i press the link my outlock openes a locate link browser

Comment: Missing "http://" perhaps?

Comment: @str unfortunatly it's not the problem :(

Comment: Try clicking on "Show Original" in Gmail and post that here.

Comment: cant recieve it on gmail on this machine since i dont have a SMTP server, i can only recieve it on outlook...

Comment: What is the the value of $link?

Comment: $link = 'stackoverflow.com';

Comment: what do you mean by "not work"? What happens when you click the link?

Comment: @Anton.P You need an `http://` call for external links. See my answer below. (tested)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many a times and in my experiences with links inside a body, the `From:` needs to be the last header entry and adding `<!DOCTYPE html>` etc.

Plus, you also need an `http://` call.

Try this:

```
<?php

$link = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
$emailTo = 'root@localhost.com';
$title =  "The title message";
$body = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><a href="'.$link.'">click me</a>  <br/></body></html>';
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0 \n" ;
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: me@gmail.com";

mail($emailTo, $title, $body, $headers);
?>
```